# Filas repetidas en consulta MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Buenas tengo un problema, resulta que tengo 3 tablas una que contiene informacion del evento, otra con los 'materiales'(servicios) para ese evento y una tabla intermedia que me genera el N a N, cuando quiero mostrar el evento con todos sus materiales se me repite el evento 
me queda algo asi

EVENTO MATERIAL1
EVENTO MATERIAL2
etc

**No se me ocurre como solucionarlo les dejo mi codigo**

```
CREATE DATABASE jumpingInflables
  DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8
  DEFAULT COLLATE utf8_general_ci;

CREATE TABLE Material (
    id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    nombre varchar(20)
);

CREATE TABLE Evento(
    id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT Primary Key,
    telefono varchar(20),
    cliente varchar(20),
    fecha date,
    horaInicio time,
    horaFin time,
    fechaRegistro date,
    cantChicos int,
    direccion varchar (32),
    observaciones varchar(32),
    costo decimal,
    duracion int
);


CREATE TABLE EventoMaterial(
    idEvento int not null,
    idMaterial int not null,
    PRIMARY KEY(idEvento,idMaterial),
    FOREIGN KEY (idEvento) REFERENCES Evento(id),
    FOREIGN KEY (idMaterial) REFERENCES Material(id)
);


INSERT INTO Material VALUES (null,'Cama Elastica chica'),
                                (null,'Cama Elastica 01'),
                            (null,'Cama Elastica 02'),
                            (null,'Cama Elastica 03'),
                            (null,'Castillo con Toro'),
                            (null,'Castillo con Rampa'),
                            (null,'Tejo 01'),
                            (null,'Tejo 02'),
                            (null,'Tejo 03'),
                            (null,'Futbolito 01'),
                            (null,'Futbolito 02'),
                            (null,'Pop'),
                            (null,'Algodon de Azucar'),
                            (null,'Musica');

INSERT INTO Evento VALUES (null,'Maria',CURDATE(),'12:30','14:30',CURDATE(),20,'Timoteo Aparicio 4169','Sin observaciones',1800,2),
                          (null,'Juan',CURDATE(),'16:30','19:30',CURDATE(),15,'Dir 2','En la calle',1600,2),
                          (null,'Lucas',CURDATE(),'21:30','23:30',CURDATE(),30,'Dir 3','En el patio',2400,3);

INSERT INTO EventoMaterial VALUES (1,1),
                                  (1,2),
                                  (2,1),
                                  (2,2);
```

**Mi consulta:**

```
"SELECT evento.*,material.nombre FROM evento,eventomaterial,material WHERE
    evento.id = eventomaterial.idEvento and idMaterial = material.id and evento.fecha = '$fecha'";
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para mi, los resultados que obtienes me parecen normales. Luego, del lado aplicativo puedes interpretar los datos como quieras.

Si de verdad solo quieres una fila por evento, la única alternativa que se me ocurre es que quieras concatenar todos los materiales juntos.  Esto se puede hacer agregando un `GROUP BY` y `GROUP_CONCAT`:

```
SELECT evento.*, group_concat(material.nombre)
FROM evento,eventomaterial,material 
WHERE evento.id = eventomaterial.idEvento 
and idMaterial = material.id
and evento.fecha = curdate()
group by evento.id
```

Te sugiero, de paso, favorecer los joins explícitos. También, en tu caso, parece buena idea usar un `LEFT JOIN` para que te devuelva los eventos sin materiales también:

```
select e.*, group_concat(m.nombre)
  from evento e
  left join (
      select em.idEvento, m.nombre
        from eventomaterial em
        join material m
          on m.id = em.idMaterial) m
    on m.idEvento = e.id
 group by e.id
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d6364b/3)